# Acumatica Web Services API Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, erp, acumatica

I am attempting to perform some basic integration using Acumatica's web services. Unfortunatly, I'm having problems logging in. According to their documentation, this process should look something like:

```
apitest.Screen context = new apitest.Screen();
context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
context.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
context.EnableDecompression = true;
context.Timeout = 1000000;
context.Url = "http://localhost/WebAPIVirtual/Soap/APITEST.asmx";
LoginResult result = context.Login("admin", "E618");
```

Simple enough. However, after creating and importing a WSDL file from Acumatica into Visual Studio, I found I don't have a Screen object. I do, however have a ScreenSoapClient object, which has a similar Login() method.

```
ScreenSoapClient context = new Acumatica.ScreenSoapClient("ScreenSoap");
LoginResult result = context.Login("username", "password");
```

That part works. In fact, the LoginResult give me a session ID. However, if I try to make any calls to the service, such as:

```
CR401000Content cr401000 = context.CR401000GetSchema();
```

I get an error: **System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> PX.Data.PXNotLoggedInException: Error #185: You are not currently logged in.**

While the version of Acumatica we're using does appear to be slightly newer, I'm unsure why the Screen() object isn't available.  Consequently, if I try a bad username/password, Login() does fail (as it should). From what I can the tell, the ScreenSoapClient class is using service model details from web.config, so it's getting the endpoint address and other details there.

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in a comment above, I was able to make contact with a representative from Acumatica. He had me remove then recreate the service references in our project and try again. That apparently did the trick and the "Error #185: You are not currently logged in" error went away.

Answer (score 3):

As i see, you use WCF to create your service reference.
So you should enable cookies in service binding:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
{
    AllowCookies = true
};

var address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/WebAPIVirtual/Soap/APITEST.asmx");

var c = new ServiceReference1.ScreenSoapClient(binding, address);
```

Or, you can use old asmx web service reference (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx).
Then everything will be same as in Acumatica`s documentation.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. After working with someone from Acumatica, we found removing then recreating the service references in our project fixed the problems. Not exactly sure why, but it did the trick!